# Twilio API Conference: How to start a participant in hold mode

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

I want to start a conference with 3 participants:

1. Client
2. Agent
3. Supervisor

Where the client would "enter" the conference in hold=true mode.

I did not find in the twilio api documentation how to do that, there is a possibility to start him in mute mode, but that does not serve our needs.

What i could do is to start the conference and then immediately put the client into a hold mode.
But is there is a proper way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: what about setting the participant as hold while creating or before joining the conference?

Comment: The conference word does not have hold parameter. The participant has. And you are putting the participant to the conference by sending him TWIML with the conference word. https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference

Comment: what about this one? https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/06/introducing-conference-hold.html

Comment: That's for putting the participant on hold after the conference already started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no way to start a participant in hold. But a conference participant on hold is not really participating in the conference.

Could you keep the user waiting by sending them to TwiML that just returned hold music using [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play) until you want to bring them into the conference by [redirecting the call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#update-a-call-resource)?

Alternatively your suggestion to have them join the conference, then immediately send them to hold will work for you.

Comment: There are still cases where joining participant with `on hold` is desired.
For example, if a participant was on hold in one conference and is transferred to another conference and is required to be on hold.


`conference participant on hold is not really participating in the conference`

Not exactly true, as when we put participant on hold via a separate request Twilio still keeps them in the conference as they are still a participant.

Using a separate request might work, but is definitely a workaround and can lead to unwanted cases when a request fails for any reason.

Comment: Ok, so your use case is that you are transferring a participant from one conference to another. Can I suggest that perhaps instead of transferring a participant on hold, you transfer your agent into the conference the participant is in? That way they don't have to move and break the hold they are on. Alternatively, once you move the participant to the new conference you can trigger an API call to immediately put them on hold. There might be a small gap in their on hold experience between the conferences, but that should work around your use case.

Comment: That is one way to do it, but there are non-obvious businesses contains that make this not an option for us. For example, we need to have separate recordings for 2 conferences. If the agent joins the first conference then we will only have one recording. Yes, we can then try to split that recording into 2, 3 or more chunks, but that process seems prone to error as well. The best option for us would be if <Conference> TwiML allowed `hold` option, similar to `muted`, but as I undestand that's not the case atm.

Comment: You can also [use the API to stop and then start a new recording](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010199074-Getting-Started-with-Call-Recording-Controls).

Comment: Here it says that `stopped not supported for conference recordings` https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording#update-a-recording-resource.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Did you consider moving the participant to a new conference and then immediately placing them back on hold? Or perhaps moving them to a queue instead of putting them on hold and then dialling them back to the conference, or into the new one, when you return them from hold?

Comment: Yes, we considered this. And we are currently actually using `putting participant on hold` immediately, which does not actually work properly and cause some corrupt audio issues (we are investigating this with Twilio support). We also considered the second option and it does not work for us, as we relly on `participant-join` webhooks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222648/discussion-between-ostap-maliuvanchuk-and-philnash).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn’t at my computer. I agree that this has a potential use, but as you said in the chat, you’re already in talks with Twilio support about it and it is indeed best to raise there along with a more in depth description of your use case so that it may influence the product team. I’m just trying to work around your problem to see if something can work for you.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for trying to help!